# Powershell - Pumping Locally Installed Applications into Listbox

Tags: powershell, listbox, foreach, powershell-2.0

So I'm trying to get all the locally installed applications and put them into a listbox. However, I'm having some problems. Whenever I use the below code:

```
$prog = (get-wmiobject win32_product -computer $current_hostname.text -property Name).Name
foreach($program in $prog)
 {
 $program_list_current.items.add($program)
 }
```

Whats returned in the listbox is the applications plus some other text/string at the beginning of each app. In some cases, where '-property Name' is replaced with ' | select Name', nothing is returned at all.

I'm using the above syntax because the below code works (which gets the AD groups for a machine and puts each group into a listbox):

```
$processnames_t = (Get-ADComputer -Identity $current_hostname.text -Property MemberOf).MemberOf 
foreach ($processname in $processnames_t)
{
[void]$AD_list_current.Items.Add($processname)
}
```

Any ideas as to why it works for the AD groups but not the installed apps? Maybe something to do with the nature of get-wmiobject?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't really repro the issue you are seeing. But, for the program names, you can replace

```
$prog = (get-wmiobject win32_product -computer $current_hostname.text -property Name).Name
```

with

```
$prog = get-wmiobject win32_product -computer $current_hostname.text | Select -Exp Name
```

Select Name alone won't work as it returns the object and not a string. In this case, to use it as a listbox item, you need the string.

Comment: So what is it that -exp does? Extract the string(s) from the object returned?

Comment: Depends on the output. -Exp is actually -ExpandProperty. So, if the output is an array, the select-object output with -ExpandProperty would be the elements / properties within that array. If you are selecting a single non-array property, you will get a string.